# Obtener la ruta de un recurso c#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente recurso includo a mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera posible de obtener la ruta del recurso o un alias para poder llamarlo?

Ya que es imprescindible que pueda saber la ruta o el alias del recurso para poder utilizarlo, por ejemplo en la función que llamara a este recurso.

```
Funcion(string ruta,string argumento)
```

En mi caso leeré el recurso y luego hare una serie de cosas:

```
private static void Funcion(string ruta, string argumento){
//existe la ruta
if (!File.Exists(ruta))
                return;
//leeme el fichero
byte[] resourcesBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
/*etc*/
}
```

¿Como podría obtener la ruta o es imposible utilizar un recurso incluido en mi proyecto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer punto que puedo marcar es que no embebas un objeto desde la carpeta \bin\Debug, es una pesima idea.
Copia el archivo y ubicalo dentro del proyecto, en otra ruta diferente.

Ademas no necesitas un resx para que el archivo se una al codigo que compilas, podrias incluirlo al proyecto y usar la opcion `Build Action`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un recurso embebido no tiene una ruta fisica, a menos que extraigas el archivo, como se explica aqui

[Saving an embedded file in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/saving-an-embedded-file-in-C-Sharp/)

Accedes al stream del assembly

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream()
```

para grabarlo en una carpeta temporal y asi poder ejecutarlo. Siempre vas a poder recuperarlo de esta forma cuando lo necesites.